# How to create linear dependent and independent vectors based on some rules.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to create linear dependent and independent vectors based on some rules. For example, suppose we have the following expressions:

1 - A and B

2 - B and C

3 - C and D

4 - A and B and D

And pre-existence vector $v_0$.

Now i want to create vectors using the following rules:

1 - When the expression has 2 elements (e.g. A and B), i want to create 3 linear dependent vectors. One we already have, that is $v_0$ and now we need to create two other vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, one for each element (A and B).

2 - When the expression has 3 elements, (e.g. A and B and D), i want to create 3 linear independent vectors for each combination of vectors including the vector $v_0$. That is, for each combination $C^3_3$: $\{v_0, A, B\}$, $\{v_0, A, D\}$, $\{v_0, B, D\}$, $\{A, B, D\}$, they must all be linear independent.

3 - When the expression has 2 elements and it is not on the list, the 3 vectors (including the $v_0$) must be linear independent (e.g. A and C). The vectors $v_0$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ must be linear independent.

4 - When the expression has 3 elements and it is not on the list, the combination of vectors must be linear dependent. For example: A and C and D. So, for each combination $C^3_3$: $\{v_0, A, C\}$, $\{v_0, A, D\}$, $\{v_0, C, D\}$ and $\{A, C, D\}$, they must all be linear dependent.

Questions:

1 - Is there a way of how to select values to A, B, C and D (vectors) that can follow the rules above?

2 - One way is to create each expression and then try to create the other adapting the vectors, but i think this is a bit too hard. I think that maybe theres a more "beautiful" method to select vectors values so that i can create such vectors following that rules. Maybe converting those logic expressions to some kind of integer values and making some transformation. But i really don't know how to do that.

Any help here is welcome!!

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What are $A,B$ for example?  Maybe it would help if you provided a few examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, i'll give more examples.

Imagine that i'm doing this for general access structures secret sharing schemes. Each A, B, C and D are participants. Each participant may receive a share to recover the secret. 

Then the expressions are the general access structures. For example, participant A and B can recover, but A and C can learn nothing about the secret.

The vector $v_0$ has one of its coordinate a secret. Now i want to build another vectors based on that rules to create the shares of each participant.
After distributing the shares, Dealer can use the shares to recover the secret.

Comment: What field are you working on? Is it finite or infinite? If it is too small, there might not even be a good solution.

Comment: Working on $Z_p$ and $p$ is a large prime. Actually it is the size of the secret of secret sharing.